# Problemas al compilar un main en C

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje C y cuando compilo la función main me compila mal (eso creo yo) y me tira el error:

> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 5s)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hola mundo");

   return 0;
}
```

Ahora me da otro error

> Cannot run program "C:\Program" (in directory "C:\Project C\Hello"): CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
>
> COMPILE FILE FAILED (exit value -2, total time: 67ms)

Me esta mostrando el hola mundo en la consola pero si es así, porque me sale ese error?

Comment: Te está dando un error al compilar el código... ¿Cómo intentas compilarlo? ¿Qué compilador usas?

Comment: Ahora me da otro problema. Estoy usando el compilador mingw y lo compilo para lenguaje C.

Comment: Para responder hace falta conocer la estructura de los archivos del proyecto y los comandos que ejecutas para generar el ejecutable